# pyspark alias for column when agg fun in with dict syntax

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, alias

When havin an iterable `list` as grouping input when using the following function by means of `agg` method in `pyspark`, I am looking for a way to adapt this code to make an alias and avoid the parenthesis of the columns output.

```
def aggregate(dataframe, grouping, aggregation, functions):
   dataframe.groupBy(grouping).agg({f"{item}": f"{functions}" for item in aggregation})
```

I reach with an output when using the function like `aggregate(dataframe, ["x"], ["foo","bar"], "sum")` format where output colnames are something like `sum(foo)` and the desired output is `sum_foo`.

But the solutions I find so far dont use this syntax, which is:

```
df.groupBy("x") \
  .agg(sum("foo").alias("sum_foo"))
```

Maybe a not optimal solution, renaming after the `agg` statement:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

func_names = [f"{function}({old_name})" for old_name in aggregation]
new_names = [f"{function}_{old_name}" for old_name in aggregation]
mapping = dict(zip(func_names, new_names))
dataframe.select([col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in dataframe.columns])
```

Comment: I want to make the same thing, did you find the solution?

Comment: I didnt... hope you find one so we can share it with the community.